# Display drop down list MVC4 with many levels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

- I have a data as below :

GROUP_CODE          GROUP_NAME            LEVEL

1                    test1                   1

2                    test2                   1

11                   test11                  2

12                   test12                  2

13                   test13                  2

111                  test111                 3

112                  test112                 3

1111                 test1111                4

- So i want to display with @Html.DropDownList as below :

test 1

```
   test11

        test111

                test1111

        test112

   test12

   test13
```

test2

Please help me to find solution ! Thank you !

Comment: Option groups will allow you to display grouped data but not hierarchical data. Select controls are rendered by the browser and you have very little control over the formatting. You will need to use a jquery plugin for this (or write your own)

Comment: @Stephen : Thanks for your reply. Do you know any plugin for this problem ?

Comment: I have my own. [Refer article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control) but not doubt google will help you find others

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks so much. I will try to use this plugin, if any i will ask to you.

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions ask them on CodeProject. Note there is a minor bug in the code and I'll be doing an update in the new year.